# Why does the Note I shared via AirDrop to my Mac from my iPhone not show up in Notes.app?

Tags: iphone, icloud, notes.app, exchange, airdrop

I can successfully AirDrop the note from my personal iPhone to my work Mac (seems to work fine), but when I go to Notes.app on my Mac - the note is not there.

I'm logged into Notes with iCloud on my iPhone and I'm logged into Notes.app with Microsoft Exchange on my Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The note will not show up in the Exchange account, but it will show up if you enable "On My Mac".

1. Open "Preferences" in Notes.app
2. Check the box next to "Enable the On My Mac account"

Now notes shared with your Mac via AirDrop will show up under "On My Mac". You can always copy these over to your Exchange account.